# Link multiple axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts for visualization . I am trying to plot [similar](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/9.3/WebUser/WebHelp/Lang_1033/creating_a_graph_matrix_visualization.htm#To_add_a_Graph_Matrix_visualization_to_an_analysis) kind of chart. I have tried it using multiple y axis and finally ended up with

```js
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 2,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            animation: false
        },
        xAxis: [{
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            categories: [
                'Q1',
                'Q2',
                'Q3',
                'Q4'
            ],
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: '#E0E0E0',
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 1,
                offset: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'power'
                }
            },
            {
                top: 300,
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 1,
                offset: 1,
                title: {
                    text: 'books'
                }
            }
        ],
        legend: {
            title: {
                text: 'Stage: ',
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                }
            },
            floating: false,
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false
            },
            column: {
                animation: false,
                grouping: true
            },
            line: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            yAxis: 0,
            name: 'Boston',
            type: 'column',
            data: [4000, 3000, 1000, 6000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Swindon',
            data: [1000, 6000, 3000, 2000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Ethiopia',
            data: [3000, 7000, 2000, 8000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Chicago',
            data: [6000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Boston',
            data: [4000, 3000, 1000, 6000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Swindon',
            data: [1000, 6000, 3000, 2000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Ethiopia',
            data: [3000, 7000, 2000, 8000]
        }, {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Chicago',
            data: [6000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. What is the question?

Comment: As per the snippet I mentioned above, data in Power and Books are not linked based on the city. It is treating each city as a different one and showing those multiple times in the legend.

Comment: Set for each main series `id`, then use [`linkedTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo) option to connect series in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

well, solution is to add `id` and `colour` to every series item (you can also define global colours instead):

```
id: "series0",
color: "red",
```

Then for the second axis series items you need to add `linkedTo: <id>` parameters. See how it works (colours specified only to 0 and 4th elements just to show that it works):

```js
$(function() {
   $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 2,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            animation: false
        },
        xAxis: [{
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            categories: [
                'Q1',
                'Q2',
                'Q3',
                'Q4'
            ],
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: '#E0E0E0',
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 1,
                offset: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'power'
                }
            },
            {
                top: 300,
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 1,
                offset: 1,
                title: {
                    text: 'books'
                }
            }
        ],
        legend: {
            title: {
                text: 'Stage: ',
                style: {
                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                }
            },
            floating: false,
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false
            },
            column: {
                animation: false,
                grouping: true
            },
            line: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            id: "series0",
            color: "red",
            name: 'Boston',
            type: 'column',
            data: [4000, 3000, 1000, 6000]
        }, {
            id: "series1",
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Swindon',
            data: [1000, 6000, 3000, 2000]
        }, {
            id: "series2",
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Ethiopia',
            data: [3000, 7000, 2000, 8000]
        }, {
            id: "series3",
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Chicago',
            data: [6000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
        }, {
            id: "series4",
            linkedTo: "series0",
            color: "red",
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            data: [4000, 3000, 1000, 6000]
        }, {
            id: "series5",
            linkedTo: "series1",
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            data: [1000, 6000, 3000, 2000]
        }, {
            id: "series6",
            linkedTo: "series2",
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            data: [3000, 7000, 2000, 8000]
        }, {
            id: "series7",
            linkedTo: "series3",
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            data: [6000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much for such a quick response @simon .